# Is there an alternative for base 64 coding for devices with api below 26?

Tags: java, android, base64

I am developing an application that uses a an authorization key to connect users to the apps server using volley. In order for the authorization key to be recognized it must be decoded with both the authorization key itself and the action the user is trying to initiate from the server 
I have this line of code that encodes the authorization key below

```
      String authkey="xxxgafjeusjsj" ;
      String action ="pay" ;
      String auth=authkey+action
      String Authkey=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth_.getBytes());
```

The above code works fine, however the last line can only be used for devices with api 26 and above. Is there an alternative code I can use for the last line of code? Please help

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64

Answer (score 0):

Use [`android.util.Base64`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64) (Added in API level 8), not [`java.util.Base64`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64) (Added in API level 26).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it now gives error cannot resolve 'getEncoder() '. what do I do about that?

Comment: Or what am I supposed to replace 'getEncoder() ' with?

Comment: , then what should be done to replace the method 'getEncoder()'

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

Then:

```
 String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(auth_.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
 byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the website doesn't recognize the authorization key